# Ejecutar codigo de pygame por consola

Tags: python, python-2.7, cmd, pygame

intento ejecutar mi programa por cmd y me sale este error

```
File "Proyecto.py", line 4
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file Proyecto.py on line 4, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

pero cuando veo el codigo en la linea 4 solo hay in comentario con # y si ejecuto el programa por spyder me lo corre sin problemas, podrian decirme cual seria el problema?

Fragmento del codigo

```
#Se importan las bibliotecas de pygame,sys,random
import pygame, sys, os, random
from pygame.locals import *
#Inicia modo gráfico    
pygame.init()
#Se crea la ventana y le damos un titulo
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((397,660))
pygame.display.set_caption('Mastermind!')
```

Segun el cmd el problema seria la 4 linea donde esta el comentario "inicia modo grafico" :(

Comment: Hola! Si pudieras poner el código en donde aparece el error, sería más fácil identificar el problema!

Comment: Alli esta, tambien debo cuando le doy doble click no se ejecuta directo, debo seleccionarlo, elegir "Editar con spyder" y recien alli lo puedo ejecutar... como puedo solucionar eso ? :(

Comment: La solución al problema del archivo es quitar la tilde del comentario: #Inicia modo gráfico.

Comment: Podrías ir al panel de control y seleccionar, en programas predeterminados, spyder para abrir archivos python, aunque bueno, esto no sería muy lógico(?

Comment: Debes especificar la codificación usada en el script en las dos primeras líneas del mismo si no usas ASCII (codificación usada por defecto por el interprete de Python 2.7 para el código fuente). Abajo a la izquierda, en la barra de estado de Spyder, te muestra la codificación que usa ese archivo, UTF-8 en principio, por lo que agrega `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`  en la primera línea del script.